# How to let and execute in the same line?

Tags: vim

I was trying to make a simple setup for Perl in Vim and used this:

```
function! PerlEnvSetup()
    nnoremap <F10> :let f=expand("%")|vnew|execute '.!perl "' . f . '"'<CR>
endf

autocmd FileType perl :call PerlEnvSetup()<CR>
```

But when I do `vim XX.pl`, the error in the bottom saying:

```
Error detected while processing function PerlEnvSetup:
line    1:
E121: Undefined variable: f
E15: Invalid expression: '.!perl "' . f . '"'<CR>
Error detected while processing FileType Auto commands for "perl":
E488: Trailing characters
```

And the window splits into two (which should not happen unless I press F10). What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing, is that the `|` is used to separate commands (and therefore explicitly ends your `:nnoremap` command.

You therefore want to use the special idiom `<Bar>` as described by the help below `:h map_bar`

Comment: Learned something new today, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
function! PerlExecuteCurrentFile()
    let f=expand("%")
    vnew
    execute '.!perl "' . f . '"'
endf

function! PerlEnvSetup()
    nnoremap <F10> :call PerlExecuteCurrentFile()<CR>
endf
```